# ThreadLocal Variable

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, thread-safety, java-threads

AS per my understanding, ThreadLocal are the variables whose values are not going to be shared among the threads, but instead it will be used by many threads.

For eg. if I have a variable whose current value is essential for each thread to process results. I will prefer to make that variable atomic or the respective method synchronized.

Does Having ThreadLocal satisfies the above condition?

I have come through a lot of post that says instead of synchronization, ThreadLocal can used as an alternative.

As I am a beginner a clear and simple explanation will help me.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I have no clue on what you are trying to ask. Your question doesn't really make sense.

Comment: @M.Deinum threadLcoal variable doesn't share their values with other threads right?

Comment: Threadlocal values are not shared. The whole point is to give each thread its own copy to work with

Comment: @NathanHughes .. can we not declare a variable inside the block of code executed by threads instead of ThreadLocal?

Answer (score 1):

It's not completely clear what you ask.

I can see two situations here:

- The variable's value changing in multiple threads and it should be visible for all threads - in this case you should use **synchronization** (`ThreadLocal` variable is not for this).
- The variable's value is initial value for multiple threads, but each thread should have it's own copy of this value and change it separately - this is for `ThreadLocal`.

Comment: The above explanation is exactly what I wanted.